# OpenMP offloading on GPU, 'simd' specificities

Tags: gpu, language-lawyer, openmp, amd-gpu, offloading

I was wondering how to interpret the following OpenMP constructs:

```
#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    // compute
}

#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for simd
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    // compute
}
```

Note the `simd` clause added on the second loop. According to the OpenMP 5.1 specification, this clause declare that: "multiple iterations of the loop can be executed concurrently by using SIMD instructions".

I believe I can very well conceive how `simd` is implemented and behaves on CPU but on GPU, more precisely, AMD GPUs, there is no such thing as exposed SIMD instruction in the sense that a HIP thread is in fact a SIMD instruction lane.

According to the OpenMP specification, if there is a loop carried dependency or if the compiler can not prove there is none, when OpenMP maps the teams to thread blocks/workgroups and the treads to simd lanes it is forced to use thread blocks of only one thread.

How do you interpret the `target teams distribute parallel for simd`:

- Does it mean that in this context `simd` can't be translated for a GPU?
- Or maybe - each thread is handled as if it had a single SIMD lane?

There is at least one similar but old and unanswered question:
[How is omp simd for loop executed on GPUs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284799/how-is-omp-simd-for-loop-executed-on-gpus)

Comment: Could it be that it is actually ignored? Have you tried running with and w/out the `simd` switch? Is there any difference in the compiled results or in the performances?

Comment: @Fra93 actually, I have tried and in practice and on loops like the one presented above (potentially with a collapse)  did not see any performance degradation or improuvent. I used the amdclang and HPE-cray compiler. Some month ago, there was no viable support for the 'simd' clause + gpu offloading on the cray compiler (it forced one thread per thread block !).

Answer (score 1):

According to the test case below, the assembly generated for AMD MI250 (gfx90a) is the same with or without `simd`. Though, if you look at the CPU code, you shall see a significant change with the `simd` clause which in this case, allows for a similar optimization to the ones observed with an explicit usage of the `restrict` keyword.

TLDR: Currently, the `simd` clause is **irrelevant** and only leads to this warning, even for extremely trivial cases:
`loop not vectorized: the optimizer was unable to perform the requested transformation; the transformation might be disabled or specified as part of an unsupported transformation ordering [-Wpass-failed=transform-warning]`.

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

#define RESTRICT __restrict

using Float = double;

void test0_0(Float* a, const Float* b) {
    a[0] = b[0] * b[0];
    // Forced store/reload (b[0] could be a[0]).
    a[1] = b[0];
}

void test0_1(Float* RESTRICT a, const Float* RESTRICT b) {
    a[0] = b[0] * b[0];
    // No forced store/reload.
    a[1] = b[0];
}

void test1_0(Float* a, Float* b, std::size_t length) {
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < length; i += 2) {
        a[i + 0] = b[i + 0] * b[i + 0];
        // Forced store/reload
        a[i + 1] = b[i + 0];
    }
}

void test1_1(Float* a, Float* b, std::size_t length) {
#pragma omp parallel for simd
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < length; i += 2) {
        a[i + 0] = b[i + 0] * b[i + 0];
        // simd -> no loop carried dependencies:
        // No forced store/reload -> easier vectorization, less generated code.
        a[i + 1] = b[i + 0];
    }
}

void test2_0(Float* a, Float* b, std::size_t length) {
#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < length; i += 2) {
        a[i + 0] = b[i + 0] * b[i + 0];
        // ASM shows forced store/reload, as expected.
        a[i + 1] = b[i + 0];
    }
}

void test2_1(Float* RESTRICT a, Float* RESTRICT b, std::size_t length) {
#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < length; i += 2) {
        a[i + 0] = b[i + 0] * b[i + 0];
        // ASM shows forced store/reload, but a/b are restricted BAD!
        a[i + 1] = b[i + 0];
    }
}

void test3_0(Float* a, const Float* b, std::size_t length) {
#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for simd
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < length; i += 2) {
        a[i + 0] = b[i + 0] * b[i + 0];
        // ASM shows forced store/reload, but a/b are restricted BAD!
        a[i + 1] = b[i + 0];
    }
}

void test3_1(Float* RESTRICT a, const Float* RESTRICT b, std::size_t length) {
#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for simd
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < length; i += 2) {
        a[i + 0] = b[i + 0] * b[i + 0];
        // ASM shows forced store/reload, but a/b are restricted BAD!
        a[i + 1] = b[i + 0];
    }
}
 test2_1(Float* RESTRICT a, Float* RESTRICT b, std::size_t length) {
#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < length; i += 2) {
        a[i + 0] = b[i + 0];
        // ASM shows forced store/reload, but a/b are restricted BAD!
        a[i + 1] = b[i + 0];
    }
}

void test3_0(Float* a, const Float* b, std::size_t length) {
#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for simd
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < length; i += 2) {
        a[i + 0] = b[i + 0];
        // ASM shows forced store/reload, but a/b are restricted BAD!
        a[i + 1] = b[i + 0];
    }
}

void test3_1(Float* RESTRICT a, const Float* RESTRICT b, std::size_t length) {
#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for simd
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < length; i += 2) {
        a[i + 0] = b[i + 0];
        // ASM shows forced store/reload, but a/b are restricted BAD!
        a[i + 1] = b[i + 0];
    }
}
```

Code available at: https://godbolt.org/z/sMY48s8jz